# Java Maximum increasingly ordered subsequence

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that has the user enter a string and display the maximum increasingly ordered sub sequence of characters. My program however is adding the characters into an array and creating multiple arrays equal to the length of the string.

The example I was given was:

> Enter a string: Welcome
>
> Result: Welo

My program has no errors in it, but my output when entering the string, "Welcome" is:

> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]
>
> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]
>
> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]
>
> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]
>
> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]
>
> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]
>
> [W, e, l, c, o, m, e]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class orderSequence {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Create Scanner for input/output
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    
    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        list.add(input.charAt(i));
        
        for(int j = i + 1; j < input.length(); j++) {
            if(input.charAt(j) > list.lastIndexOf(list)) {
                list.add(input.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        
        if (list.size() > al.size()) {
            al.clear();
            al.addAll(list);
        }
        list.clear();
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(al);
    }   
    
}
}
```

Comment: As for me I don't understand what should be done. Can you add more examples and give more extensive explanation of the problem?

Comment: I'll paste the books problem as it's all I have the information on what I'm supposed to do. Above I posted what my output is, different from the books output. (Maximum increasingly ordered subsequence) Write a program that prompts
the user to enter a string and displays the maximum increasingly ordered subsequence
of characters. Analyze the time complexity of your program. Here is
a sample run:

Comment: It's supposed to take the highest character and put them in an ordered sequence

Comment: This is very vague, I have no idea what they want and how Welcome becomes Welo.

Comment: Why Welo and not Wclo? And not Wcmo?

Comment: I agree, I think that's why I've had a hard time trying to do this exercise. I need the output to just be one array sorting the characters in ascending order.

Comment: @Devin are you trying to sort the characters? Like `cab` becomes `abc` or `cba`? Could edit your question to add an example of the result you want?

Comment: The first quote above, "Welcome" becoming "Welo" is the only example I was given. I believe cab should become abc yes.

Comment: It looks like for the input `12945` the output should be `1245`. And your current solution (even fixed as @MrWayFarOut suggests) won't be able to do that. You should try to apply dynamic programming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens on the line `if(input.charAt(j) > list.lastIndexOf(list))`. The `lastIndexOf` function returns the index where the object you pass in last occurs. Well, you're passing in the list itself, and nowhere in `list` is one of the elements `list` itself. So the `lastIndexOf` method returns -1. Thus you do `character at j > -1` which is always true, and that is why your method constantly returns the entire string in the array.

Take a look here for more information about [lastIndexOf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_lastindexof.htm).

And the way to fix your method is to do `if(input.charAt(j) > list.get(list.size() - 1))` instead

And the reason that it is repeating 4 times is because of the `for` loop you have at the bottom. The size of `al` is 4, so the for loop runs the code inside of it 4 times, so it'll print out `al` 4 times.

Comment: My output has become "[W, e, l, o]" now repeated 4 times, the size of the array. So it's now sorting the way I want. Thanks!

Comment: yah of course, be sure to mark this as the answer so other people know this solved the issue

Comment: Yeah still to early to accept haha, but do you know why it's repeating the array four times instead of just once?

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.out.print(al.get(i))` instead of `System.out.println(al)`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a dated questions, but I think that it can still benefit from some clarification. The task at hand is to find the length of the longest subsequence of a given sequence such that all elements of the subsequence are sorted in increasing order.

Look at the string "Welcome" in its decimal string form {87, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109, 101}. The longest increasingly ordered subsequence is {87, 101, 108, 111} or "Welo".